# Add a bias to a score using a graph function

Tags: java, math, equation

I am trying to update a calculator written in Java that places data in an order according to several criteria.  The ordering is arrived at by a scoring system.  Each criteria adds a certain amount to the score for each item and then the data is presented in score order once all calculations are done.

One of the criteria I want to add is the proximity to one of 3 dates.  Each piece of data has a date value and that is associated with a window of time, and I want the score addition to be at it's highest if:

- The data item has just entered the window
- The data item is just about to leave the window
- The data item's date is the current date

The data item might not be within the window bounds, in which case the score addition would be zero.  If it is in the window, I would want the score addition to be gradually less the further from these 3 points the data item is, ideally described by a graph equation.

Unfortunately, my experience of graph equations is next to zero so I'm not sure where to start beyond maybe some combination of sin, cos or tan.  Ideally I want to be able to write a method like:

```
public double getPositionInWindowScore( Date itemDate, Date windowStart, Date windowEnd ) {
  if( itemDate.before( windowStart ) || itemDate.after( windowEnd ) {
    return 0.0;
  }
  ...
}
```

I could create some clunky code with a load of if's in it but I'm pretty sure there will be a more elegant way that someone with much better math skills than I could suggest.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you want to get convolution with some kernel. Filter kernel describes coefficients for elements in the window. Look for gaussian filter as example

Comment: Better to make this a continuous scaling function rather than discrete with if/else.

Comment: Thanks for getting me started guys, I have just been on holidays so will be making a start on this soon!